# Server side working fine client side giving 0 in Android

Tags: java, android

In the below code System.out.println(groupdetails); gives 0, But parms got printing the correct values.

From server side it's working fine but from client side giving 0.  Where did I make a mistake?

**java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
        setContentView(R.layout.list_screen);

        friendAdapter = new FriendListAdapter(this);
        try {
            imService=Login.imService;
            String groupdetails = imService.DispalyGroupDetails(imService.getUsername());
            System.out.println(groupdetails);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }    

    }
```

**imService.DispalyGroupDetails**

```
public String DispalyGroupDetails(String username) throws UnsupportedEncodingException  {


            String params = 
                        "username="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.username,"UTF-8") + 
                        "&password="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.password,"UTF-8") +
                        "&action="  + URLEncoder.encode("DispalyGroupFDetails","UTF-8")+
                        "&";

            Log.i("PARAMS", params);
            return socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);      


    }
```

**socketOperator.sendHttpRequest**

```
public SocketOperator(IAppManager appManager) { 
    }


    public String sendHttpRequest(String params)
    {       
        URL url;
        String result = new String();



        try 
        {
            url = new URL(AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS);
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            out.println(params);
            out.close();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result = result.concat(inputLine);              
            }
            in.close();         
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

        if (result.length() == 0) {
            result = HTTP_REQUEST_FAILED;
        }

        return result;


    }
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat entries of the error?

Comment: @ThahzanMohomed see my logcat

Comment: What is the code line at line number 191 in FriendList.java?

Comment: String result1 = imService.DispalyGroupDetails(imService.getUsername());

Comment: Looks like the `imService` object is null

Comment: ownusername = imService.getUsername(); this one return the result as user2

Comment: You are trying to get a value from `imService` in `onCreate` without initializing the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `imService` is `null` because you are starting bound service as normal service so `imService` is not initialized. to start bound service use `bindService` instead of `startService` :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Login.this,  IMService.class);
this.bindService(intent,mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: Hi then also giving NPE

Comment: @user1: probably `imService` is `null` ?

Comment: String result1 = imService.DispalyGroupDetails(imService.getUsername()); this is line number 191

Comment: ownusername = imService.getUsername(); then this one also it will give Null but this returns the user2 suppose imservice =null means

Comment: @user1: yes `imService` is `null` because you are  initlizling `imService` in `Login` Activity but trying to access it in `FriendList`

Comment: where I want to access the Login.imService can you please edit the code

Comment: I have a small doubt how to display the groupname

Comment: @user1: where you want to display group name?

Comment: friend list activity I am displaying all the friends same activity how to display groupname

Comment: Your not understanding my problem or what?

Comment: @user1: you want to display `groupname` in FriendList right? but where you want to access `groupname` in FriendList?

Comment: From grouplist.java activity I am getting the groupname

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70686/discussion-between-user1-and--k).